# como evitar que se borren mis selecciones en spinners en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-spinner

Necesito navegar en varias pantallas para llenar pedidos en diferentes spinners pero al seleccionar, salir y regresar a la pestaña donde estan mis spinners ya no tienen lo que seleccione y quiero evitar eso quiero que se quede lo seleccionado, uso varios spinners que las opciones a seleccionar se carganpor bases de datos en sqlite.

si alguien me puede ayudar le compartiria el codigo de la pestaña necesaria.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
   package com.example.room;

   import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
   import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

   import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.Spinner;

  import com.example.room.BD.BDconexion;
  import com.example.room.BD.BDconexion1;
  import com.example.room.BD.BDconexion2;
  import com.example.room.BD.BDconexion3;
  import com.example.room.BD.BDconexion4;
  import com.example.room.modelo.Bebida;
  import com.example.room.modelo.Cena;
  import com.example.room.modelo.Comida;
  import com.example.room.modelo.Desayuno;
  import com.example.room.modelo.Menu;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner spMenu;
Spinner spDesa;
Spinner spCo;
Spinner spCe;
Spinner spBe;
Spinner spBeb;

EditText edt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    edt=findViewById(R.id.editText);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    spMenu = findViewById(R.id.spmenu);
    List<Menu> lleMenus = llenarmenu();
    ArrayAdapter<Menu> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<> 
(getApplicationContext(), androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,lleMenus);
    spMenu.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    spDesa=findViewById(R.id.spdesa);
    List<Desayuno>lleDesas=llenardesayuno();
    ArrayAdapter<Desayuno> arrayAdapter1=new ArrayAdapter<> 
(getApplicationContext(), androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,lleDesas);
    spDesa.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);

    spCo=findViewById(R.id.spco);
    List<Comida>lleComidas=llenarcomida();
    ArrayAdapter<Comida> arrayAdapter2=new ArrayAdapter<> 
 (getApplicationContext(), androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,lleComidas);
    spCo.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);

    spCe=findViewById(R.id.spce);
    List<Cena>lleCenas=llenarcena();
    ArrayAdapter<Cena> arrayAdapter3=new ArrayAdapter<> 
(getApplicationContext(), androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,lleCenas);
    spCe.setAdapter(arrayAdapter3);

    spBe=findViewById(R.id.spbe);
    List<Bebida>lleBebidas=llenarbebida();
    ArrayAdapter<Bebida> arrayAdapter4=new ArrayAdapter<> 
(getApplicationContext(), androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,lleBebidas);
    spBe.setAdapter(arrayAdapter4);

    spBeb=findViewById(R.id.spbeb);
    List<Bebida>lleBebidasBebidas=llenarbebida();
    ArrayAdapter<Bebida> arrayAdapter5=new ArrayAdapter<> 
    (getApplicationContext(), androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,lleBebidasBebidas);
    spBeb.setAdapter(arrayAdapter5);

    spMenu.getLastVisiblePosition();
    spDesa.getLastVisiblePosition();
    spCo.getLastVisiblePosition();
    spCe.getLastVisiblePosition();
    spBe.getLastVisiblePosition();
    spBeb.getLastVisiblePosition();
}

@SuppressLint("Range")
private List<Menu> llenarmenu(){
    List<Menu> listaM = new ArrayList<>();
    BDconexion bDconexion = new BDconexion(MainActivity2.this);
    Cursor curso= bDconexion.mostarCategorias();
    if (curso != null){
        if(curso.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Menu me= new Menu();
                
       me.setMenu(curso.getString(curso.getColumnIndex("Menu")));
                listaM.add(me);
            }while(curso.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    return listaM;
}
@SuppressLint("Range")
private List<Desayuno> llenardesayuno(){
    List<Desayuno> listaD = new ArrayList<>();
    BDconexion1 bDconexion1= new BDconexion1(MainActivity2.this);
    Cursor cu= bDconexion1.mostarDesayuno();
    if (cu != null){
        if (cu.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Desayuno de=new Desayuno();
                
     de.setDesayuno(cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("Desayuno")));
                listaD.add(de);
            }while(cu.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    bDconexion1.close();
    return listaD;
}
@SuppressLint("Range")
private List<Comida> llenarcomida(){
    List<Comida> listaC = new ArrayList<>();
    BDconexion2 bDconexion2= new BDconexion2(MainActivity2.this);
    Cursor cur= bDconexion2.mostarComida();
    if (cur != null){
        if (cur.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Comida co=new Comida();
                
       co.setComida(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Comida")));
                listaC.add(co);
            }while(cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    bDconexion2.close();
    return listaC;
}
@SuppressLint("Range")
private List<Cena> llenarcena(){
    List<Cena> listaCe = new ArrayList<>();
    BDconexion3 bDconexion3= new BDconexion3(MainActivity2.this);
    Cursor cur= bDconexion3.mostarCena();
    if (cur != null){
        if (cur.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Cena ce=new Cena();
                
           ce.setCena(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Cena")));
                listaCe.add(ce);
            }while(cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    bDconexion3.close();
    return listaCe;
}
@SuppressLint("Range")
private List<Bebida> llenarbebida(){
    List<Bebida> listabe = new ArrayList<>();
    BDconexion4 bDconexion4= new BDconexion4(MainActivity2.this);
    Cursor curs= bDconexion4.mostarBebida();
    if (curs != null){
        if (curs.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Bebida be=new Bebida();
                
     be.setBebida(curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex("Bebida")));
                listabe.add(be);
            }while(curs.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    bDconexion4.close();
    return listabe;
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
este es el codigo que uso para las conexiones y para llenar los spinners que uso

Comment: Hola, recuerda agregar lo que estas realizando a tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: ya agregue el codigo que hace el llenado de spinners

Comment: Lectura recomendada [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 0):

Hola deberías usar el método onResume() ahí puedes configurar lo que quieres mostrar al cambiar pantallas

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/400974)